# Heroku is driving me nuts! Is my code amazingly sloppy, or is Heroku amazingly picky?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

wow. going super nuts here trying to deploy to staging on heroku cedar from Rails 3.2.2. I've gotten everything to work, but I wanted to run these issues up the flagpole to see if there's something wrong with... me. eheh

Both of these issues give me the not-helpful "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error page. So it was frustrating when I had 2 different issues (that acted like 3) in one deploy (that worked fine on my local).

#### Heroku won't give me my logs.

when I run

```
heroku logs
```

I get a long error message that starts with,

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': Permission denied - connect(2) (Errno::EACCES)
```

so i've been doing all this troubleshooting via small slices of commits. maddening.

### Heroku chokes when it can't find an image with image_tag

this works on heroku:

```
= image_tag("content/portfolio/maskphoto_rubble_rebel_blur.jpg", :alt => params[:photo], :width => "100%")
```

This doesn't (only difference is an extra letter in the file name, though it works on my local):

```
    = image_tag("content/portfolio/maskphoto_rubble_rebell_blur.jpg", :alt => params[:photo], :width => "100%")
```

Am i nuts in thinking that heroku should just serve up the image tag as-is and let it just not display, rather than crashing the entire page? I'm running compass; not sure if that has anything to do with anything.

### Heroku hates nested expressions in an array ref

this works:

```
n = f.index(params[:photo]) +1
@nextphoto = f[ n ]
```

this doesn't (but does on my local):

```
@nextphoto = f[ f.index(params[:photo]) +1 ]
```

i guess it's better form to separate expressions, but still. why would it work on my local and not on deploy?

Answer (score 2):

I can't directly answer all of your questions, but here are a few things to look at:

> **Heroku won't give me my logs.**

The error you are getting indicates `Permission denied` ... Perhaps your account credentials are not setup properly? I see you are on a windows box ... on a unix machine, the `heroku` client writes a file at `~/.heroku/credentials` with the username and what appears to be an API token. Check to see if you have a similar file. You can also check https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/windows and make sure you have successfully performed the `heroku login` command.

> **Heroku chokes when it can't find an image with image_tag**

I don't have many ideas here. Perhaps it is related to the asset-pipeline?

> **Heroku hates nested expressions in an array ref**

This one doesn't make a whole lot of sense either. Perhaps the logs can shed some light here. I did notice that you appear to be running Ruby 1.9.3 on your system, and I don't believe heroku supports 1.9.3 yet. Maybe you have hit a version-specific bug.

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks; I'll take a glance. I am running a mismatch of ruby, which is frustrating, but heroku broke into all kinds of entertaining errors when I tried following some instructions to upgrade, so i stuck with the mismatch for now. ;)